# Please wait until the service objective assignment state for the database is marked as 'Completed' error message

Tags: azure

We have three databases in Azure SQL that appear to be locked. We run the query

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] MODIFY(EDITION='basic',SERVICE_OBJECTED='basic')
```

or

```
ALTER DATABASE [DBName] MODIFY(EDITION='standard',SERVICE_OBJECTED='S2')
```

and end up with the error message; "A service objective assignment on server '[ServerName]' and database '[DBName]' is already in progress. Please wait until the service objective assignment state for the database is marked as 'Completed'."

They have been sitting in this state, with a little clock next to the Edition for several days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I haven't found a solution to prevent this, but I am able to get around it by exporting the offending database, deleting it and then creating it again from the export.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the database state using ServiceObjectiveAssignmentState Property before performing any db changes

Rest Api: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn505708.aspx

Powershell: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dn546735.aspx

Comment: Is ther any way to Query the ServiceObjectiveAssignmentState  property from t-sql?

Answer (score 0):

I have just been in the same state, and managed to get access again after running a succesfull export of the database.

I have marked a database to be scaled from S2 to S3, from the web interface it just showed as upgrade in progress for over 40min.

When using powershell i could see the **CurrentServiceObjectiveId** did not match the **RequestedServiceObjectiveId** meaning the request was made.

```
Get-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup_WestEurope" -ServerName "Server-WestEurope" -DatabaseName "TestingAutomatedScaling"
```

When trying to Set the database back of forth in state using powershell

```
Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup_WestEurope"
-ServerName "server-westeurope" -DatabaseName "TestingAutomatedScaling" -Edition "Standard"
-RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S2"
```

and -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S3"

I got

> A service objective assignment on server '[ServerName]' and database
>   '[DBName]' is already in progress. Please wait until the service
>   objective assignment state for the database is marked as 'Completed'

But I could not see the progress state anywhere. 
The database was only 15Gb in size... so a 40min+ worktime seems like a blocked state.

Now for the magic part... 
After doing an export of the database, first attempt got me an error.

```
serviceRequestId:47881ba1-5a56-492f-8307-455dbb95c18d statusMessage:{"code":"0","message":"There was an error that occurred during this operation : '<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">Error encountered during the service operation. ; Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unable to authenticate request; </string>'","target":null,"details":[{"code":"0","message":"There was an error that occurred during this operation : '<string xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/\">Error encountered during the service operation. ; Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unable to authenticate request; </string>'","target":null,"severity":"16"}],"innererror":[]}
```

Doing it again, the export happened to work.

After the export was successfull the database came back online and was marked as S3. Until further testing I wont know if i just needed to wait or if exporting the database helped unblock. But information might be helpful to anyone else finding the topic.